# intellij - Spring Application Context Dependencies diagram

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

using IntelliJ ultimate edition, I would like to get a diagram containing multiple XML contexts with all the beans and their (circular) dependencies.

Does this work only for context files and/or does it also include the beans? :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-diagrams.html#application-context-dependencies

As written in the description:

> The Spring Application Context Dependencies diagram lets you view
>   dependencies between multiple configuration files and analyze how they
>   include and reference each other.

In intellij, I cant see the option
 `diagram->show diagram->Spring Application Context Dependencies`
 after right-clicking the configuration file.

**Questions:**

- Does this diagram include beans and their references between contexts?
- Why can't I see the right-click option to generate the diagram? Is some plugin required?

Comment: Yes, see these screenshots for the relevant settings: https://i.imgur.com/JO7rNXM.png
https://i.imgur.com/W9VILVu.png
https://i.imgur.com/DdevWLj.png .

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get the diagram for one file, but it does not show the beans from the others. Whenever I select multiple files and right-click, the option to generate a diagram is not present.

Comment: "Bean dependencies" diagram is loaded in "local context" mode and shows beans from current file only. You can click "Local context" button and load all beans/dependencies.

https://i.imgur.com/CfdMydw.png
https://i.imgur.com/xeAakVf.png .

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks very much. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bean dependencies** diagram is loaded in *local context* mode and shows beans from the current file only.

You can click on the **Local context** button to load all the beans/dependencies:

[image: Local context]